# Unable to load Json data to collection view in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Here i am trying to load json data into collection view but got crashed in data source method `numberOfItemsInSection` here the model class count is returning nil don't know why can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

here is the code which i had used

```
var listClassModel : ModelClass?

listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL()
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self

func listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url = URL(string: listPageUrl)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil { print(error!); return }
        do {
            if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                self.listClassModel = ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject])
                    print(self.listClassModel)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard let obj = self.listClassModel else { return }
                    let itemsCount = obj.items.count
                    print(itemsCount)
                    for i in 0..<itemsCount {
                        let customAttribute = obj.items[i].customAttribute
                        for j in 0..<customAttribute.count {
                            if customAttribute[j].attributeCode == "image" {
                                let baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product"
                                self.listCategoryImageArray.append(baseUrl + customAttribute[j].value)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    print(self.listCategoryImageArray)
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    self.collectionView.isHidden = false
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.init(width: ITEM_WIDTH , height: ITEM_HEIGHT)
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let arr = listClassModel?.items
    return (arr!.count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arr is optional in some case it is nil. Make sure arr is not nil or use the following code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let arr = listClassModel?.items
        return arr?.count ?? 1 //setting default 1, you can set as per your requirement
}
```

Comment: actually after entering into these methods the data needs to call from here self.listClassModel = ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject]) but it is not calling any reason for this ?

Comment: seems like all errors are due to missing basic checks like nil checks array count check. make sure about these checks hopefully your code will run. In this case your listCategoryImageArray has zero items as printed on console and you are try to access the array.

Comment: actually listcategoryimagearray needs to be loaded from data but it is not calling api when the break point reaches @Amit Battan

Comment: it in the code u can see listcategoryimagearray i am new to swift 3 first time i had written model class any wrong with it please help me bro

Comment: then call the webservice first in async call and on getting response reload the collectionview on main thread.

Comment: how to do bro i don't know i am new to swift 3

Comment: and in this i am calling web service in async call only

Comment: you already doing the same on listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL()... what value is printing for listCategoryImageArray after for loop. if listCategoryImageArray has zero items then you should return correct number of items for colloectionview section and row. ... it seems like that you are returning some other value for colloectionview section and row and getting value from somewhere else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156087/discussion-between-amit-battan-and-user).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let arr = listClassModel?.items
    if arr!.count > 0
    {
    return (arr!.count)
    }
    else
    {
     return 0
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
first declare listCategoryImageArray as global
and then this func

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let arr = listCategoryImageArray.count
    if arr > 0
    {
    return (arr)
    }
    else
    {
     return 0
     }
}
```